# Drawing Custom View

Tags: android, android-custom-view, shapes

I want to create a custom view which has check mark inside a circle. Refer image below.

Drawing circle would be easy. I need some suggestion on drawing tick mark.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You might look into vector drawables using paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have a specific requirement to create a custom view, I recommend simply using a vector drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:pathData="M0 12a12 12 0 1 1 0 0.01z"
        android:fillColor="#8ab88c"/>

    <path
        android:pathData="M5.25 12l4.5 4.5l9 -9"
        android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
        android:strokeWidth="2.5"/>

</vector>
```

The first `<path>` element uses the elliptical arc command to draw the circle, and the second uses two "lineto" commands to draw the check.

This can be used inside an `ImageView` with any dimensions you'd like and will scale beautifully.

If you must implement a custom view, I would use the same general technique inside my `onDraw()` implementation:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    rectF.set(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, fillPaint);

    float checkmarkWidth = getWidth() * 0.5626f;
    float delta = checkmarkWidth / 3.0f;

    float initialX = (getWidth() - checkmarkWidth) / 2.0f;
    float initialY = getHeight() / 2.0f;

    path.reset();
    path.moveTo(initialX, initialY);
    path.rLineTo(delta, delta);
    path.rLineTo(2 * delta, -2 * delta);

    strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(getWidth() / 9);
    canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [LayerDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) you can draw an array of drawables where the element with the largest index will be drawn on top.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check" />
</layer-list>
```

Or you can use a [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html), right click on drawable folder > new > vector asset > icon > search "check circle".